# Целочисленный тип со знаком и без знака

Tags: c#

В чем различия между типом со знаком и без знака?

Comment: А вы попробуйте написать a = 0; a--; и посмотреть на результаты для знакового и беззнакового типов.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Целочисленные типы со знаком отличаются от типов без знака способом интерпретации старшего разряда целого числа. Если в программе указано значение тип которого со знаком, то компилятор C# сгенерирует код, в котором старший разряд этого числа используется в качестве флага знака.

Число будет считаться положительным, если флаг знака равен 0, и отрицательным, если он равен 1.

Последний бит переменной это флаг знака.
Если он равен 1, то это отрицательный элемент, а если 0, то положительный.

Например: есть знаковое число размером 1 байт. Значение этого числа **0**0000001 - это положительная единица, а такое значение **1**0000001 это отрицательная единица. Из-за того, что знаковые переменные используют 1 бит для определения знака, то само число умещается(в моем примере) в **7** бит, а у без знакового в **8** бит.

Из-за этого положительный диапазон знакового значения будет меньше чем у без знакового

Comment: На книге Шилдт так написано. Но там не понял что такое флаг знака

Comment: Последний бит переменной это флаг знака. Если он равен 1, то это отрицательный элемент, а если 0, то положительный. Например: есть знаковое число размером 1 байт. Значение этого числа  **0**0000001 - это положительная единица, а такое значение **1**0000001 это отрицательная единица. Из-за того, что знаковые переменные используют 1 бит для определения знака, то само число умещается(в моем примере) в **7** бит, а у без знакового в **8** бит. Из-за этого положительный диапазон знакового значения будет меньше чем у без знакового.

Answer (score 3):

Различия в диапазоне значений.

Например обычный `int` принимает значения от -2,147,483,648 до 2,147,483,647

Беззнаковый `uint` - от 0 до 4,294,967,295

Происходит это потому что для хранения знака резервируется первый бит, и на собственно число остается 31 бит (для `int`, для других типов будут свои значения), в случае беззнакового числа для хранения значения числа используется все 32 бита

[остальные типы](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx)

Comment: ох, как режут глаз `резервируеться` и `используеться`

Answer (score 2):

Тип со знаком хранит информацию о знаке. Он позволяет хранить отрицательные числа.

Тип без знака хранит только положительные числа и ноль.

Ваш кэп.